# How do I create a library with interface function for user to define in c++?

Tags: c++

For example, if I want to create a shared library like below, but I want to leave `virtual void Work();` undefined to give people using this library freedom to implement the behavior suitable for their environment.
But I know if i leave `Work()` undefined in this library, the compiler will give errors. How can I achieve that in C++? 
Or is it just a bad design?

```
class Contaniner
{
public:
    void Factory(int code, int size)// Construct specified type
    {
        if(code == 1)
        {
            products.push_back((Product *)new A(size));
        }
        else if(code == 2)
        {
            products.push_back((Product *)new B(size));
        }
    }
    void Init()// Run every product's AdjustSize() function
    {
        for(auto i : products)
        {
            i->AdjustSize();
        }
    }
    void Run()// Run every product's Work() function
    {
        for(auto i : products)
        {
            i->Work();
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<Product *> products;
};

class Product
{
public:
    Product(int size) : m_size(size) { }
    virtual void AdjustSize() = 0;
    virtual void Work() = 0;
protected:
    int m_size;
};

class A : public Product
{
public:
    A(int size) : Product(size) {}
    virtual void AdjustSize() { //adjust the m_size }
    virtual void Work();// leave it to user to define
};

class B : public Product
{
public:
    B (int size) : Product(size) {}
    virtual void AdjustSize() { //adjust the m_size }
    virtual void Work();// leave it to user to define
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove it from the definition of classes A and B. Let the users of the shared linrary provide it's implementation - they need to do so, because the function is pure virtual in the Product class.

The idea is to provide just the interface that has to be implemented.

Comment: But if l remove it from classes A and B, the library wouldn't pass the compile `error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type`  and  `because the following virtual functions are pure`